# Data Recovery on reformated drive is encrypted

Tags: windows-8, data-recovery, formatting

I used Data Recovery Pro by Pareto Logic and when recovering the files it suddenly crash, the files recovered is now encrypted and I tried to scan again but didn't work. Any help, or suggestions is a big help.

The disk is accidentally formatted, and my system is windows 8.1.

The txt file example content is like this:

```
1a20 429b 8ab0 c34f 02a4 e23d c746 66db
4b33 c7d4 7d46 cc4a 1b17 b848 33a1 4177
f430 5f40 85bd 17a0 c249 150e be34 faf8
98ea f0fd bea3 cf26 625f bf9b f6c5 8013
c7a0 a060 b59a d4c0 2d6f 2bde ba8b a235
dcd8 c94b 721a 6a1f 463e a7cc f6a9 8b8e
f52c 4926 6b1c 176f d2d7 9c2a 7285 4181
8206 1d8d b0a0 548a 2e33 4bec 24b1 59be
5fee 2fd2 4daa 9733 1591 c39a cc4e 74c1
3bef 4e36 a9ad 5250 af62 afdf abd5 7227
fbeb 7bbe 4e9e ef2e f17a bb53 4f4b f264
49eb 9f93 fd93 b1cb c91b 7775 1766 7f18
09d6 367b 5dd1 e0f1 8a62 2eab 13f3 7bbb
c552 f40d d497 15a5 0bd0 5646 ded1 520a
a161 3d73 aa36 618d 8d21 4130 5316 1e32
b858 a188 e0d2 a007 003c 93a1 5048 8843
0650 7d96 bc16 269b 83d7 4894 1547 bcc9
91f4 96b6 efe9 bebe 218c e143 4c7a 2dfc
```

Comment: Encrypted or scrambled? There is a difference and if this happened after a crash using a data recovery program, you're just getting digital noise.

Comment: I would ask for (1) assistance, and (2) my money back if a commercial disk recovery tool destroyed my data.

Comment: I added example txt file content, this is the content of the files i recovered

@AndreasF, yes I already contacted them but I'm tired waiting on reply.

Answer (score 0):

The entry is in hexadecimal form and shows the files recovered are either corrupt or in inaccessible form. Consider asking for refund (If you had paid the price) and try another software.

One question, are you trying to scan and recover data using the demo version?